# Socket io emit from server catched by server itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My io is somehow catching its own emits

I console log the given socket to validate it catches the "wrong" emits.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket);
  ...
}
```

Outside my io.on(...) { ... } I have something like this

```
io.emit('connection', { my: 'object'});
```

When this is called my console log triggers and logs given data even though it's supposed to emit to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any specific reason for this, but it just seems to be a problem with the term **connection**.

It works perfectly well when changing it to

```
io.emit('con', data);
```

And listen to this on client side.